# Insert into specific table if the user session group

Tags: mysql, php

I am trying to insert data into specific table by user session and group.

The tables are `users`, `workers`, `help`.

*Structure of table "users":*

```
id | username | password | group
---+----------+----------+---------
1  | john     | 123      | workers
2  | david    | 123      | help
```

*Structure of table "workers" and "help":*

```
id | username | message
```

I finished login with session pages and include session onto every page.
So when the user login it check and display from "user" table session: Hello "user"

The problem is with "insert into" statement, when john or david logs in and then they post something into database.

Which is the best way to create insert into statement so if it's john all insert into will go into "workers" and if it's david all insert into will go into "help"?

Comment: When you said *then they post something into database*, do you mean they post a message in the table `workers`? And can you clear if you want a  log table for the session or do you want to write in the table `workers` only when the `group` for the current username be `workers`?. Anyway, why don't you make a table with the group_id and you can log every message for any user, not splitting them in tables like `workers`, `help` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This look s like a job for Dynamic SQL

For this example, let's use `david`

STEP 01 : Look up the `id` of the `username`

```
SELECT id INTO @userid FROM users WHERE username = 'david';
```

STEP 02 : Create the SQL string to insert based on the `id` of `username`

```
SET @m = 'Whatever my message is supposed to be';
SELECT
CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',B.group,' (username,message) VALUES (''',B.username,''',''',@m,''')')
INTO @dynamic_sql
FROM information_schema.tables A INNER JOIN users B
ON A.table_name = B.group AND A.table_schema = DATABASE()
WHERE B.id = @userid;
```

STEP 03 : Compile and Execute the SQL

```
PREPARE s FROM @dynamic_sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

or in your case, just use the formatted SQL in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they're is a good idea to divide all group message in different tables. You should make a table and storage your `user_id` and `group` fields, or even better, just the user because `users` table have the `group` field, and you can easily join and filter it with this field.

### Proposition:

Make a table named `message`:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, -- remember that you could avoid this field because you have it in `users` table.
  `mdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And you just have to make and `INSERT INTO` this table.

```
INSERT INTO test.message
    (id,user_id,`group`,mdate,message)
VALUES
    (@id,@user_id,@group,@date,@message);

@ = Your user and message information variables.
```

And if you have only your `user_id` and you want to bring all the `workers` group messages:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.username,
    u.`group`,
    m.mdate,
    m.message
FROM test.users AS u
JOIN test.message AS m ON (m.user_id=u.id)
WHERE u.`group`='workers'
ORDER BY m.mdate ASC;
```

*Note: Adding indexes on `u.group` and `m.mdate` would be helpful.*

But, if you want to still do it with your actually design, you can make a compare or switch in Php level for the group, so you can easily know if belongs to `workers` or `help` table. Or you can make a **[*Stored Procedure*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)** and make the code inside it.